# Is this the correct way to use GROUP BY and ORDER BY clauses on mySQL?

Tags: mysql

The table is named "Franchises" with the columns "Advertising", "Sales", "Franchises", "Customers", and "Age"

Select all the franchises where sales is less than $150,000. Group It by owner age of franchise in descending order.

Is this a correct query?

```
SELECT Franchises, Sales, Age
FROM Franchises
WHERE Sales < 150,000
GROUP BY Age
ORDER BY DESC
;
```

Comment: `DESC` is a SQL keyword meaning "Descending;" the `ORDER BY` clause also requires one or more fields that you want to ORDER BY.

Comment: You woudn't normally store 'age', and you'd normally omit thousands separators. An you have to ORDER BY *something*

Comment: When you group by `Age`, the rows included in a group may contain different values for `Franchises`. This renders the usage of `Franchises` in the `SELECT` clause invalid (because the engine cannot know what value to select for `Franchises`). This renders the entire query invalid and MySQL will reject it (unless it is older than version 5.7.5 or it is configured to accept such invalid queries). Use an [aggregate (`GROUP BY`) function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/aggregate-functions-and-modifiers.html) instead.